# Magento 2 how to add image upload from product page as a attribute

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, xml, custom-attributes

How to add product attribute which is a image uploader. I have tried few methods none of them are working.

I have tried this following code which didn’t get me anywhere it doesn’t show up in my product page in admin area.

```
  $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'color_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'color_image',
                'input' => 'media_image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 30,
                'frontend' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Frontend\Image::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Media attributes are grouped in the image section of a product (admin panel) so if you click on the image section you should be able to choose your attribute this being said you should be able to create this in the backend of magento

Comment: How can I create a separate image uploader that’s what I am trying to do

Comment: You would need to create your own source model to do this

Comment: Is there something I could follow I am using Magento 2.3.5